# Is my proof correct? It can't be this simple

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, alternative-proof, normal-operator

I am just starting to  learn about linear algebra. My lecturer gave me the following exercise, and said 'it's quite an interesting exercise':

$\text{Show that the identity operator $\hat{\mathbb{1}}$ can be written as a sum of outer products of an eigenbasis: $\hat{\mathbb{1}} = \sum_{i = 1}^N \lvert \mathbf{x}^i> <\mathbf{x}^i \rvert$}$

Sorry, I am not sure how to typeset the identity operator or how to do dirac notation without a latex package.

Below is my proof. It seems to simple to be right, so I am hoping to get some feeback.

$\textit{Proof.}$

We know that any linear operator $\hat{\mathbf{A}}$
can be written as a sum of the outer product of its eigenvectors with themselves, weighted by the corresponding eigenvalue: $\hat{\mathbf{A}} = \sum_{i  = 1}^N \lambda_i \lvert \mathbf{x}^i \rangle \langle \mathbf{x}^i \rvert$. Using the definition of the identity operator $\hat{\mathbf{}1}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}$, we see that any vector is an eigenvector for the identity operator, and each eigenvalue $\lambda_i = 1$. Thus, we can build a basis from any $N$ linearly independent vectors and they will be eigenvectors for $\hat{\mathbb{1}}$, and
we can write the identiy operator like this: $\hat{\mathbb{1}} = \sum_{i = 1}^N 1 \times \lvert \mathbf{x}^i \rangle \langle \mathbf{x}^i \rvert = \sum_{i = 1}^N \lvert \mathbf{x}^i \rangle \langle \mathbf{x}^i \rvert$ as required.

**EDIT**: The theorem I assumed doesn't actually require the operator to be normal after all, and thus I don't need to show that the identity operator is normal, so I have removed that part of the proof.

QED

Comment: Can you expand on the "we know" bit?  Like, recite a precise theorem statement, plus reference to where you got it, or a pithy summary of its proof?

Comment: The theorem is proved earlier in the course I am doing, so I am allowed to assume it. I don't know the name of the theorem sorry, but I can provide a summary of the proof:

Comment: I would be happy with a precise statement.

Comment: `\langle` and `\rangle` ("left angle" and "right angle") look a lot better as angle brackets than `<` and `>`: compare $\langle x\mid y\rangle$ to $<x\mid y>$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how I could be more precise. The theorem is stated exactly as I stated it. The eigenvectors of A form an orthonormal basis, and we can write the operator as a weighted sum of the outer product of each eigenvector with itself, where the eigenvalues are the coefficients. Which part of it was unclear?

Comment: thanks @Arthur I will change it!

Comment: @kimchilover a proof of the theorem I assumed is given in this video https://youtu.be/WcMv0hrpqVo?t=1535, starting from 25:30

Comment: @kimchilover Actually that theorem applies to all linear operators, not just normal ones, but I think my proof should still hold, I just don't need the step where I say the identity operator is normal.

Comment: $(1,0)$ and $(1,2)$ form an eigenbasis of the identity matrix $I$, but do not obey your your recipe, because $I\ne\pmatrix{2&2\\2&4}$.  There is some set of added assumptions or funny terminology you are holding back.

Comment: Yes, an assumption could be "positive compact operator". But then it will not be the case for your operator. But actually you do not need to use this theorem at all. Just define the operator $A = \sum  |x_j\rangle\langle x_j|$. And then prove that $Ax = x$, and conclude that $A = Id$.

Comment: @LL3.14 thanks, it was even simpler than I thought huh. After that hint, it was really easy to complete the proof. Thanks!

Comment: I think it has to be an orthonormal eigenbasis, but I see it would still not result in the identity matrix. I'm not sure why? Using the hint from @LL3.14 it was very easy to prove it, so surely it must be right. I think I am not understanding the theorem correctly, because I thought any orthnormal basis should work for the identity operator